# PhpStorm Xdebug: Port 9000 is busy, yet set at port 63342

Tags: windows, phpstorm, port, xdebug

I have just installed Xdebug and as soon as I start PhpStorm, I get to see this message:

[image]

This is due to some other program running port 9000 that I'd like to leave alone:

```
C:\Users\Rsluimers
λ netstat -ab
...
TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           LT1736:0               LISTENING
[aeagent.exe]                                                  
...
```

So I set the Xdebug debugger port in PhpStorm settings:

[image]

and in php.ini:

```
...
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=63342
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp"
```

Yet after a full reboot the same error appears.

Comment: same error on port 63342 or 9000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger` is the **wrong place** to set/get debugger port for PHP.

This settings page has nothing to do with PHP debug: it's for JavaScript debug integration/LiveEdit plugin/IDE own communications/built-in web server.

---

**The correct place is** `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug`.

HINT: If you would use search box and searched for "xdebug" you would find it straight away (it really helps narrowing down possible locations/reduce places where to look for the stuff).

[image]

Comment: Well that makes me feel stupid. >_<;  Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Sometimes i use xdebug without problem but i dont know the reason when next debug says Port 9000 is busy. I restart phpstorm and it work again but why happpend? maybe outlook, slack, xamp or any app? Like happend with xamp and skype (Conflict with ports i remember)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a Setting in "**Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger**":  I used the same port in there, not knowing that this setting is NOT for the remote but inline debugger.

Effectively, due to this setting phpStorm itself locked the port intent for remote debugging right at startup.

Remote debugging worked IMMEDIATELY once I changed the above setting to another port.

Hope this helps somebody.

Cheers.